# About a gaussian prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, gaussian-integers

I have a question:

Let gcd$(a,b)=1$ and assume that $a+bi$ is a gaussian prime. How can we prove that $a^2+b^2$ is prime using the result found in [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373073/quotient-rings-of-gaussian-integers?rq=1)

**My idea:** If I can show that $\Bbb Z[i]/\langle a+bi\rangle$ is a field then using [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373073/quotient-rings-of-gaussian-integers?rq=1), it follows that $\Bbb Z_{a^2+b^2}$ is a field and hence $a^2+b^2$ is prime. Am I correct or is there any simple way of proving it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said yourself, if you can show that $\Bbb Z[i]/\langle a+bi\rangle$ is a field, you are done. But this is exactly the problem, so you are going in circles. A solution is given in this duplicate:

[$a+bi$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ if and only if $a^2+b^2$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367917/abi-is-prime-in-mathbbzi-if-and-only-if-a2b2-is-prime-in-mathbb)

Also interesting for the converse is this question:

[If $a^2 + b^2$ is a prime number $p$, with $p \equiv 1$ (mod $4$), then $a + bi$ is prime in the Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001252/if-a2-b2-is-a-prime-number-p-with-p-equiv-1-mod-4-then-a-bi/2001255)